# Using markdown, is it possible on hover to display text of a different part of the page or another page altogether?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

In my markdown document I have certain personally defined keywords that I would like to have a description for shown on hover. I will be using those keywords several times within the document, but ideally I would like to write the description for that keyword in one place, either a text paragraph that is part of the same page or another page.

As an example, let's say I have a keyword **Cheese** that has this paragraph describing it:

---

```
# Cheese
"Cheese is a dairy product produced in a wide range of flavors, textures, and forms by coagulation of the milk protein casein."
```

## Cheese

"Cheese is a dairy product produced in a wide range of flavors, textures, and forms by coagulation of the milk protein casein."

---

Then let's say I have a paragraph of text with **Cheese** written several times:

"**Cheese** is good, **Cheese** is great, **Cheese** is the best"

I would like for each instance of that keyword to show the paragraph written above for Cheese on hover, similar to this:

"**[Cheese](https://stackoverflow.com/)** is good, **[Cheese](https://stackoverflow.com/)** is great, **[Cheese](https://stackoverflow.com/)** is the best."

The problem is that the markdown looks like this, with redundant tooltip descriptions written for each instance of the **Cheese** keyword:

```
"**[Cheese](## "Cheese is a dairy product produced in a wide range of flavors, textures, and forms by coagulation of the milk protein casein.")** is good, **[Cheese](## "Cheese is a dairy product produced in a wide range of flavors, textures, and forms by coagulation of the milk protein casein.")** is great, **[Cheese](## "Cheese is a dairy product produced in a wide range of flavors, textures, and forms by coagulation of the milk protein casein.")** is the best."
```

---

If possible, I would like to be able to edit the paragraph/tooltip description for the keyword **Cheese** in one place and have it be reflected for every instance of that keyword in the markdown.

I'm planning on hosting the markdowns as static files (github or gitlab pages), so pointers to any markdown rendering or processing with that in mind that can give me this option is most welcome.

Comment: No, this isn't something built into Markdown or GitHub's variant of it. (Side note, the syntax you show here badly abuses links. You'd be much better off using a more semantically appropriate HTML tag. [`<abbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/abbr) isn't perfect here, but it's better than a link. Or maybe a `<span>` with a `title` attribute.)